# Silent fail on setup/deploy

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I want to deploy a new 1.4 Meteor project to our servers. I switched to [kadirahq](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) branch for compability issues of mupx. I'm running on Windows 10, using npm v3.10.7 and mup v1.0.3

When I try to setup/deploy, mup exits silently and there's nothing in output. The config I'm using looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '{host}',
      username: '{username}',
      pem: 'private.ppk'
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'et',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\X\\Projects\\Y',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: '{host}',
      PORT: 3004,
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },
    //dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration? What would be the best way to identify the issue?

Comment: I've had issues with the kadirahq version of mup, and decided to switch to mupx. i made sure to change the docker image to abernix/meteord:base instead of the default, and things are working great right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it in verbose mode to see the error?

https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up#troubleshooting

You should be able to find where it is breaking here

Comment: no output whatsoever, for some reason I cannot run mup from the directory it's initialized in, but going to the root project folder and passing config/settings fixed the problem